# Python - Calling Variable From (Static) Method of One Class in Method of Another Class

Tags: python, class, methods, pyqt, static-methods

I am making a GUI in PyQt and need to connect the graphic creation classes and methods of my script with its analytics class methods. I've tried doing this by simply calling the analytics method from within the graphic method (as seen below) but this results in a "global name 'UsersPerPlatform' is not defined" error so this clearly doesn't pull the dictionary from the other method.

```
class Analytics():

    @staticmethod
    def UsersPerCountryOrPlatform():
        ...
        return UsersPerCountry
        return UsersPerPlatform #both are dictionaries

class UsersPlatformPie(MyMplCanvas): #irrelevant parent

    def compute_figure(self):
        Analytics.UsersPerCountryOrPlatform() #running function to return UsersPerPlatform
        for p, c in UsersPerPlatform:
            print 'If I could access the UsersPerPlatform dictionary I would plot something!'
```

I'd like to avoid combining the two methods into one as this will disorganise my file but I will consider changing the method type of the static method if necessary.

Comment: In your code above, your static method has two returns, one after the other, and there's no info on where `UsersPerPlatform` comes from. Is it supposed to be the return value from your static method? / Can you clear up/fill in the rest of the relevant code, please?

Comment: That info is extraneous to the question. All that is relevant is that yes, the static method returns two dictionaries.

Comment: @JonathanConnell no, it returns single dictionary. Second return statement is unreachable code.

Comment: Exactly! Also, in your case, you're not catching the return value: `UsersPerPlatform = Analytics.UserPerCountryOrPlatform()`

Comment: Keep in mind that `UsersPerPlatform` does not exist in `UsersPlatformPie`, hence your `for` tries to access a variable that doesn't exist.

If your return from `UsersPerCountryOrPlatform` works properly, put `Analytics.UsersPerCountryOrPlatform()` into a variable.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski I think this method returns only one of them, depending on a condition the OP didn't want to reveal.

Comment: It is simply bad syntax on my part, I mean to return both but still as separate dictionaries. The answer below is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access local namespace from called function - but you can easily access return value from any called function.

```
class Analytics:
    @staticmethod
    def UsersPerCountryOrPlatform():
        ...
        return UsersPerCountry, UsersPerPlatform

class UsersPlatformPie:
    def compute_figure(self):
        myUsersPerCountry, myUsersPerPlatform = Analytics.UsersPerCountryOrPlatform()
        print(myUsersPerCountry)
        print(myUsersPerPlatform)
```

Comment: I only want p, c in the UsersPerPlatform part of what Analytics.UsersPerCountryOrPlatform() returns (i.e. no UsersPerCountry data).